# Azure AD B2C login with Firebase Auth Capacitor plugin: Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, capacitor

I use [this Capacitor plugin](https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/authentication/docs/setup-microsoft.md) to Auth with MS. But no luck yet.

I have followed [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth#before_you_begin) and configured it all well.

But can you tell me where to set this up?

> When registering apps with these providers, be sure to register the
> *.firebaseapp.com domain for your project as the redirect domain for your app.

**Error**

> The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error
> getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is:
> https://my-app-123a2.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response:
> OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_reques

This is an Ionic/Angular Native app on an Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved in the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-firebase/issues/74#issuecomment-1107418833

Make sure you select `Web` as the platform for your redirect URI when registering a Microsoft OAuth client.